# How to get response code in java

Tags: java

I want the response code in my program
kindly tell me what is the error in my following code

```
  public class Main{
      public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = openConnection();


        System.out.println("Response code is " + httpCon.getResponseCode());
     }
    }
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: openConnection(); you mean url.openConnection(); ??

Comment: Please give us the stacktrace/error and the code of `openConnection()`

Comment: I think OP meant `url.openConnection()`. They define a local variable, then they call a method with no parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


    System.out.println("Response code is " + httpCon.getResponseCode());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is obvious man.

`openConnection()` is a method of `URL` class and not defined in your class. You must use an object of URL class which you have created earlier.

Call to openConnection() method must be like this-

`url.openConnection()` It returns a `URLConnection` object you will have to typecast this object to `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason** for the problem is that the compiler is telling that the Class constructors(URL), and methods (`openConnection` ..)  throwing Exceptions (defined in their `signatures`) and take some necessary steps.

You have 2 options:

`Throw` the checked exception's from your main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                System.out.println("Response code is " +
                                              httpCon.getResponseCode());
             }
```

or

catch that `Exception` ,using `try catch block.`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection httpCon;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            System.out.println("Response code is " + httpCon.getResponseCode());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put `url`
change it to `HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();`

```
package naveed.workingfiles;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Url {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        System.out.println("Response code is " + httpCon.getResponseCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the object to  HttpURLConnection

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    //Cast the object to  HttpURLConnection
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    System.out.println("Response code is " + httpCon.getResponseCode());
 }
}
```